# Detect excerpt of string from strings in a vector in R

Tags: regex, r, stringr

Using a vector (a column of a data frame) of strings, I'm trying to identify the string from which an excerpt of a string comes.

In the following example, `excerpt_of_string` is an excerpt (specifically the first 119 characters) from the second element in `vector_of_strings`:

```
excerpt_of_string <- "Considering utilizing eLearning days for snow make-up? Join us on 12/8 for Snow day, sNOw problem! Details https://t.co"

vector_of_strings <- c("Meow", 
                       "Considering utilizing eLearning days for snow make-up? Join us on 12/8 for Snow day, sNOw problem! Details https://t.co/LfbPne3uuo #INeLearn", 
                       "Bark")
```

I first tried to use `grepl`, anticipating that the second element of `vector_of_strings` would be `TRUE`, but all the elements were false:

```
grepl(excerpt_of_string, vector_of_strings)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I also tried `str_detect` from the `stringr` package:

```
stringr::str_detect(vector_of_strings, excerpt_of_string)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Why are these methods not detecting the excerpt `excerpt_of_string` in the second element of `vector_of_strings`?

Comment: Use `stringr::fixed(excerpt_of_string)` instead of `excerpt_of_string`.

Comment: That works, thanks (I used `stringr::str_detect(vector_of_strings, stringr::fixed(excerpt_of_string))`). The help says that is used to "Compare literal bytes in the string." can you help me understand what that means / why this works?

Comment: I don't have time to track down the specific point in your `pattern` string where things break down, but it's almost certainly due to the fact that it contains character like `?`, `!`, `:`, and `.`, which generally aren't interpreted literally by regex engines. You need `fixed = TRUE` (`grepl`) or `fixed(...)` (`stringr`) to search for literal character strings.

Comment: Read the **Extended Regular Expressions** section in `?regex`, particularly  *"The metacharacters in extended regular expressions are . \ | ( ) [ { ^ $ * + ?, but note that whether these have a special meaning depends on the context."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not detecting because of the metacharacters that reside in your string.

You can treat the entire string pattern as a literal using the `fixed=TRUE` parameter.

```
grepl(excerpt_of_string, vector_of_strings, fixed=TRUE)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Or `\Q` ... `\E`, which can be used to ignore metacharacters in the pattern as well.

```
grepl(paste0('\\Q', excerpt_of_string, '\\E'), vector_of_strings)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```